# Stretch link over it's parent table cell

Tags: html, css

I have a table of links which should look like this:

[image]

So I wrote code like this:

```css
body, html {
    padding:0px;
    margin: 0px;
    background-color: black;
}
#THR_CHOICE a {
    background-color: lightblue;
    /* to allign text in middle */
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-radius: 4pt;
    color: black;
    font-size: 13pt;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
#THR_CHOICE {
    text-align: center;
    }
#THR_CHOICE {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    width: 99vw;
    height: 99vh;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<table id="THR_CHOICE">
        <tr>
            <td><a href="http://www.example.net">ALB</a></td>
            <td><a href="http://www.example.net">HRA</a></td>
        </tr>                   
        <tr>                    
            <td><a href="http://www.example.net">LIS</a></td>
            <td><a href="http://www.example.net">NOS</a></td>
        </tr>                
        <tr>                 
            <td><a href="http://www.example.net">PRE</a></td>
            <td><a href="http://www.example.net">SLV</a></td>
        </tr>             
        <tr>              
            <td><a href="http://www.example.net">SOK</a></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

As you can see, the links are refusing to spread both vertically and horizontally. What's the trick?

Answer (score 0):

Its because you have you `<a>` tags with `display: table-cell;`. Elements with this display need a parent with `display: table;` I believe... and your `<a>` have a parent (`<td>`) which is another `display: table-cell;`.

You can use `display: flex;` instead to achieve what you are after:

```
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
```

```css
body, html {
    padding:0px;
    margin: 0px;
    background-color: black;
}
#THR_CHOICE a {
    background-color: lightblue;
    /* to allign text in middle */
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-radius: 4pt;
    color: black;
    font-size: 13pt;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
#THR_CHOICE {
    text-align: center;
    }
#THR_CHOICE {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    width: 99vw;
    height: 99vh;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<table id="THR_CHOICE">
        <tr>
            <td><a href="http://www.example.net">ALB</a></td>
            <td><a href="http://www.example.net">HRA</a></td>
        </tr>                   
        <tr>                    
            <td><a href="http://www.example.net">LIS</a></td>
            <td><a href="http://www.example.net">NOS</a></td>
        </tr>                
        <tr>                 
            <td><a href="http://www.example.net">PRE</a></td>
            <td><a href="http://www.example.net">SLV</a></td>
        </tr>             
        <tr>              
            <td><a href="http://www.example.net">SOK</a></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Or if you don't want to use flex you would have to change your markup...

CSS:

```
#THR_CHOICE span {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

HTML

```
<td><span><a href="http://www.example.net">ALB</a></span></td>
```

```css
body, html {
    padding:0px;
    margin: 0px;
    background-color: black;
}

#THR_CHOICE span {
display: table;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}

#THR_CHOICE a {
    background-color: lightblue;
    /* to allign text in middle */
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-radius: 4pt;
    color: black;
    font-size: 13pt;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
#THR_CHOICE {
    text-align: center;
    }
#THR_CHOICE {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    width: 99vw;
    height: 99vh;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<table id="THR_CHOICE">
        <tr>
            <td><span><a href="http://www.example.net">ALB</a></span></td>
            <td><<span>a href="http://www.example.net">HRA</a></span></td>
        </tr>                   
        <tr>                    
            <td><span><a href="http://www.example.net">LIS</a></span></td>
            <td><span><a href="http://www.example.net">NOS</a></span></td>
        </tr>                
        <tr>                 
            <td><span><a href="http://www.example.net">PRE</a></span></td>
            <td><span><a href="http://www.example.net">SLV</a></span></td>
        </tr>             
        <tr>              
            <td><span><a href="http://www.example.net">SOK</a></span></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: And how do I achieve the vertical stretch?